# Python Dictionary: Multi keywords key with single identical value

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.8

I am trying to create a dictionary as follows:

key( file_size checksum ) = filename.

I want the double keywords to make up a key taking into account both value. These keys are derived from the actual file in question. If the key is matched, I have a duplicate file, not just a duplicate file name.

It is easy  to determine duplicity if there was a single key:filename. But not all files will have the same filename, either by path or in actual filename. So far, no Python website has been able to supply an answer. Although one did have this format, I haven't found it again.

I have tried various combinations of brackets and commas with little effect.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to use a pair of values as a dictionary key? `your_dict[1, 2] = 'foo'` for example?

Comment: "have tried various combinations of brackets and commas" - that's the problem right there, you should not program by throwing syntax at a compiler and see what sticks. Try to read up on why those different brackets and commas are there, what they mean and find the structure that matches your problem. Something like `dict[tuple[int, int], str]` - i.e. tuples of int (`(1, 2)`) as keys to string values in a dictionary sounds like what you need.

Comment: Yes, I am trying your_dictp1,2] = 'foo' where foo happens to be a file name with filesize 1 and hash 2. Point taken on subset of file for hash.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example that finds duplicate files in subdirs using a dictionary like you suggest:

```
from pathlib import Path
import hashlib


found = {}
for fn in Path('.').glob('**/*'):
    if fn.is_file():
        with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
            key = (fn.stat().st_size, hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest())
        if key in found:
            print(f'File {fn} is a duplicate of {found[key]}')
        else:
            found[key] = fn
```

Specifically, `key` is a `tuple` of two integers, the first the file size and the second an MD5 hash (i.e. a sort of checksum, as you suggest).

Note that this bit of code reads every file it encounters in its entirety, so I suggest pointing it at a small or moderate file collection. Computing a full checksum or hash for each file isn't a very fast way to find duplicates.

You should consider looking at more basic attributes first (size, hash for the first few bytes, etc.) and only doing a full hash if you have candidates for being duplicates.

Also, the odds of two files having the same MD5 hash, but somehow different sizes is astronomically small, so adding the file size to the key here is more or less pointless if you hash the whole file.

(Edit) This is a somewhat better way to achieve the same, a lot faster:

```
from pathlib import Path
import hashlib
import filecmp


found = {}
for fn in Path('.').glob('**/*'):
    if fn.is_file():
        with open(fn, 'rb') as f:
            key = (fn.stat().st_size, hashlib.md5(f.read(1024)).hexdigest())
        if key in found:
            if filecmp.cmp(fn, found[key], shallow=False):
                print(f'File {fn} is a duplicate of {found[key]}')
        else:
            found[key] = fn
```